# Can anybody resolve this error for my discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I try to implement cogs on my discord.py bot and it work but it seems that my slash command doesn't work even though I typed in the commands.

This is my main.py file

```
import discord
import os
import math
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
from online import keep_alive
from itertools import cycle
from fractions import Fraction
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands = True)

status = cycle([
  " Unanswered Question of Life", 
  " Self - Referential Paradox", 
  " Near-infinite density?", 
  " Dark matter ?", 
  " Measurement of the speed of light in one straight line", 
  " Schrodinger's cat ???"
  "436c69636b2074686973206c696e6b20666f72206672656520766275636b7320212121212121203a200a68747470733a2f2f7777772e796f75747562652e636f6d2f77617463683f763d6451773477395767586351 (try to decrypt this)",
  "The light side of Discord is the path of many unnatural abilities"
])

cogs = ['cogs.update']

@ client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  status_swap.start()

@ tasks.loop(minutes = 5)
async def status_swap():
  await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(next(status)))

keep_alive()
for cog in cogs :
    client.load_extension(cog)
client.run(os.getenv('MATH_VAR'))
```

This is cogs file

```
import discord
import os
import math
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
from online import keep_alive
from itertools import cycle
from fractions import Fraction
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, cog_ext


class UpdateCode(commands.Cog) :
  def _init_(self, client) :
    self.client = client

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Add two numbers")
  async def add(ctx, x: float, y : float) :
    def addition(x : float, y : float) :
      return x + y
    response = (f"The result of addition between {x} and {y} is {addition(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Substract two numbers")
  async def subs(ctx, x: float, y : float) :
    def substraction(x : float, y : float) :
      return x - y
    response = (f"The result of substraction between {x} and {y} is {substraction(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Multiply two numbers")
  async def multi(ctx, x: float, y : float) :
    def multiplication(x : float, y : float) :
      return x * y
    response = (f"The result of multiplication between {x} and {y} is {multiplication(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Divide two numbers")
  async def div(ctx, x: float, y : float) :
    def division(x : float, y : float) :
      return x / y
    response = (f"The result of division between {x} and {y} is {division(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Squared a number")
  async def square(ctx, x: float) :
    def squarePower(x : float) :
      return x ** 2
    response = (f"The result of {x} squared is {squarePower(x)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Cubed a number")
  async def cube(ctx, x: float) :
    def cubePower(x : float) :
      return x ** 3
    response = (f"The result of {x} cubed is {cubePower(x)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Power a number to another number")
  async def varpower(ctx, x: float, y : float) :
    def numPower(x : float, y : float) :
      return x ** y
    response = (f"The result of {x} to the power of {y} is {numPower(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Square root a number")
  async def squareroot(ctx, x: float) :
    def squareRoot(x : float) :
      return math.sqrt(x)
    response = (f"The result of square root of {x} is {squareRoot(x)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Cube root a number")
  async def cuberoot(ctx, x: float) :
    def cubeRoot(x : float) :
      return x ** (1./3.)
    response = (f"The result of cube root of {x} is {cubeRoot(x)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Root a number to another number")
  async def varroot(ctx, x: float, y : float) :
    def numRoot(x : float, y : float) :
      return x ** (1./y) 
    response = (f"The result of {x} root {y} is {numRoot(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Produce a randomise number between two numbers")
  async def generator(ctx, x: int, y : int) :
    def randomNum(x : int, y : int) :
      return random.randint(x,y)
    response = (f"The randomised number between {x} and {y} is {randomNum(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "z(1): Hypotenuse. z(2) : Opposite side. z(3) : Adjacent side.")
  async def pytha(ctx, x : float, y : float, z : int) :
    def pythagoras(x : float, y : float, z : int):
      if z == 1 :
        return math.sqrt((x**2) + (y**2))
      elif z == 2 :
        if x > y :
          return math.sqrt((x**2) - (y**2))
        else :
          return math.sqrt((y**2) - (x**2))
      elif z == 3 :
        if x > y :
          return math.sqrt((x**2) - (y**2))
        else :
          return math.sqrt((y**2) - (x**2))
    if z == 1 :
      response = (f"The hypotenuse of side {x} and side {y} is {pythagoras(x, y, z)}.")
      await ctx.send(response)
    elif z == 2 : 
      response = (f"The opposite side of side {x} and side {y} is {pythagoras(x, y, z)}.")
      await ctx.send(response)
    elif z == 3 : 
      response = (f"The adjacent side of side {x} and side {y} is {pythagoras(x, y, z)}.")
      await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Convert an angular degree value to degree, minutes and second.")
  async def degminsec(ctx, x : float):
    def decdeg2dms(x : float):
      negative = x < 0
      x = abs(x)
      minutes,seconds = divmod(x*3600,60)
      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes,60)
      if negative:
        if degrees > 0:
          degrees = -degrees
        elif minutes > 0:
          minutes = -minutes
      else:
        seconds = -seconds
      return (degrees,minutes,seconds)
    response = (f"Once converted, {x} becomes {decdeg2dms(x)} in the form of degrees and minutes.")
    await ctx.send(response)

  @ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "z(1) : Sine. z(2) : Cosine. z(3) : Tangent.")
  async def trigoratio(ctx, x : float, y : float, z : int) :
    def trigono(x : float, y : float, z : int) :
      return Fraction(x/y).limit_denominator()
    if z == 1 :
      response = (f"The sine for opposite side {x} and hypotenuse {y} is {trigono(x, y, z)}.")
      await ctx.send(response)
    elif  z == 2 :
      response = (f"The cosine for adjacent side {x} and hypotenuse {y} is {trigono(x, y, z)}.")
      await ctx.send(response)
    elif z == 3 :
      response = (f"The tangent for opposite side {x} and adjacent side {y} is {trigono(x, y, z)}.")
      await ctx.send(response)

def setup(client) :
  client.add_cog(UpdateCode(client))
```

So when I try to use one of my slash commands which was add, this error pop out.

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `add`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1352, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 209, in invoke
    return await self.func(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: add() got multiple values for argument 'x'
```

So, can anybody spot any mistakes on my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. This isn't enough to go off of.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only popped out when I tried the command. Almost all the time, it's something about "x/y/z has multiple values" just  like the error I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is short on details on how to deal with slash commands that have options, but from the [migrations page](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) it looks like you need to register the options explicitly. Perhaps code like this is what you need?

```
  @cog_ext.cog_slash(
    description="Add two numbers",
    options=[
      manage_commands.create_option(
        name="x",
        description="The first number to add",
        option_type=float,
        required=True
      ),
      manage_commands.create_option(
        name="y",
        description="The second number to add",
        option_type=float,
        required=True
      ),
    ],
  )
  async def add(ctx, x: float, y: float) :
    def addition(x: float, y: float) :
      return x + y
    response = (f"The result of addition between {x} and {y} is {addition(x, y)}.")
    await ctx.send(response)
```

Caveat: this code is completely untested, so there is no guarantee that it will work. If you still have problems, it is probably best to ask on the [discord-py-slash-command Discord](https://discord.gg/KkgMBVuEkx).